# Don't allow further value assignment to a variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to override future assignment of a variable in Makefile.

Here in the below code snippet, I want `DEFCONFIG` to be assigned with `$(src)/board/$(BOARD)/defconfig`, ignoring further assignments.

```
 ifdef BOARD && $(BOARD) == "abc"
 DEFCONFIG := $(src)/board/$(BOARD)/defconfig 
 endif
```

if any other makefile redefines DEFCONFIG, that value shouldn't be effective.
How can I do that?

Comment: What is your `make`? The example code looks very strange.

Answer (score 0):

> if any other makefile redefines `DEFCONFIG`, that value shouldn't be effective. How can I do that?

Don't redefine it in other makefiles then.

One way to achieve that is to assign to a makefile-specific variable, rather than to same variable `DEFCONFIG`:

```
DEFCONFIG.$(BOARD) := $(src)/board/$(BOARD)/defconfig 
DEFCONFIG.def := ...
DEFCONFIG.xyz := ...

DEFCONFIG := ${DEFCONFIG.abc}
```

Comment: I don't have the flexibility to change other makefiles. All I want to do is invalidate subsequent assignments to a variable. Is there any such possibility?

Comment: @shim_mang You can choose a different variable name or be the last assigner to it, after you have included all other makefiles (unless you use recursive makefiles).

Comment: I am actually using recursive makefiles. I just have flexibity to change 1 intermediate makefile and not other makefiles which will be called later.

Answer (score 0):

> if any other makefile redefines DEFCONFIG, that value shouldn't be effective. How can I do that?

Since you appear to be using GNU `make`, you can use the the `?=` operator to assign its value.  If you do this consistently for all assignments to that variable then only the first assignment processed will be effective (or none of them if the variable take a value from the environment).

Answer (score 0):

In GNU make you can use `override` keyword.

```
override DEFCONFIG := $(src)/board/$(BOARD)/defconfig
```

Since `override` has the highest priority, it can be overridden only by another `override`.

However, there certainly is some flaw in your project, if you have to use this.